# Love2D: Stop the player from moving, when I press up or down

Tags: lua, love2d

This is how my player moves:

```
if love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
    player.x = player.x + player.speed * dt
end

if love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
    player.x = player.x - player.speed * dt
end
```

I want to make it, so when the up or down button is pressed down, stop the player from moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap those if statements in another, using the `not` and `and` keyword:

```
if not love.keyboard.isDown("up") and not love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
   -- Your left/right movement checks here
end
```